# Show top rated questions with given tag from selected period

Tags: discussion, tags, search, tag-search

as for top rated question with selected tag I can go to tag page and click tab `votes` and I get top rated questions, but I don't see an option to choose period from which those questions would be taken. I can only see all questions.

On the other hand, when I go to main page of stackoverflow where are questions with all tags I can click tabs `week` or `month`, so in this case it is possible to filter top questions by selected period, but I don't see an option to filter those questions with tag(s).

So it is possible to get best questions from chosen period, but then I can't filter them by tag. Also there is possibilty to get top question with chosen tag, but I can't limit those questions to some time period.

Any possibility to have this two things combined? Get top questions tagged with chosen tag and limit them only to last month, week, day or other time period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can with using the `created` parameter in the search

- [`[java] created:7d`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+created%3A7d)
- [`[java] created:2015`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+created%3A2015)
- [`[java] created:2015-11-01..2015-12-01`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+created%3A2015-11-01..2015-12-01)

Those parameters are explained in [Advanced Search Options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: Thanks, I also needed to add `is:question` to get only questions, because by default search returns questions and answers, And second thing to clear up is that `created:7d` returns posts from seven days ago, not posts from last seven days.

Comment: To get posts from last seven days I needed to change from `created:7d` to `created:7d..`.